# Unable to update file attributes: Access denied

Tags: .net, security, permissions, io

The following code, running as administrator from local hard drive, using the .Net Framework 2.0, sometimes raises an `UnauthorizedAccessException` on the second line:

```
IO.File.SetAttributes(File, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
IO.File.SetAttributes(File, IO.FileAttributes.Archive)
```

This happens on a network drive. The faulty files have weird permissions (see end of post), although reading and writing work perfectly.

Worse, even from Explorer, trying to change permissions fail, first asking for admin rights, then failing anyway:

[image: Access denied, requiring admin rights] 
[image: Failing anyway]

Any ideas? I'm at a complete loss.

---

Here's a screenshot of file permissions:
This one works:

[image: Authorized access]

This one does not:

[image: Unauthorized access]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know French much at all( that is the language correct?) but it looks like the first one works because you are a user on the server side (Linux user). When working over network drives, you have to have permissions on the server to change file attributes. Otherwise, it will have to be changed on the server end.

Edit: Some servers also can change file permissions when saved to a network drive depending on the server settings and type of file. These changes may be locked down to only someone with server credentials can modify them and the code then fails with that exception.

Edit2:  It's also possible that it also could be tied down on the server end by indexing and after a few minutes, you will get acccess back.

Comment: That's French, but it doesn't say anything but "Access Denied". How comes the files can be written to, but their attributes can't be changed?

Comment: @ Clement Perhaps the file is accessed as read-only for indexing, virus monitoring on the server, or possibly the server side changed attributes and by doing so, changed the permissions, even if you originally saved the file their with your credentials. On the local network where I work, I've seen that happen with certain file types.

Comment: Server could also change ownership of the file as well and prevent attribute modification.

Comment: @ Clement Do you have access to the network or server side or someone who does? Perhaps they can add you to the user group that will give you access to these files as well.

Comment: Additionally, when from explorer it asks for admin rights, it may refer to those on the network side, which you probably don't have

Comment: Spot-on =) Here's the full explanation: the files causing these exceptions had been created just after I set some a password on my NAS. soon after I removed it, and reset the user config on the NAS (full rights for everyone). It's precisely those files which had been modified inbetween which caused this security exception: the corresponding user didn't exist anymore. The problem is solved by copying the files again.

Comment: @ Clement Ahh that's why there was that user name with the ? by it; he was the user who didn't exist anymore!